# API calls through Switch Statements

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have two tableViews, The **first table view** has fixed data which never will be changed. When a user taps on a specific cell for example cell number 1, an **API 1** is called and the **2nd table view** is loaded with the returned data when cell number 2 is tapped **API 2** is called the **2nd table view** is loaded with the returned data.

To solve this issue I have tried this.

In my ***first Table View*** I record of which table cell was tapped and send that information to the ***2nd table view*** via prepare for segue:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? BioListTableViewController {
      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        if let row:Int = indexPath?.row {

              // PASS which cell was tapped by the user
              destination.cellTapped = row
         }
       }
     }
```

Then within my **2nd table view** I use a switch statement which checks whether the cell tapped was 0,1,2 and so on. And based on that a switch case is run. Each switch case has a different function which calls a different API. See below:

```
 import UIKit

 struct Note {

    var name:String
    var job:String
  }

 struct WeatherSummary {
     var id: String
 }

class BioListTableViewController: UITableViewController {


  var cellTapped = Int()

  @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

  private var notes = Array<Note>()

  var bioArray = NSArray(){

    didSet{
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    switch cellTapped {

    case 0:
        test()
    case 1:
        testTwo()
    default:
        println("Error")

    }

    var newItem:Note = Note(name: "", job: "")

    for x in bioArray {
        if let id = x["employeeName"] as? String{
            newItem.name = id
        }
    }

  }

  func test() {

    println("This is TWEST")

    var weatherArray = [WeatherSummary]()
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "myAPI-Link")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true  
    var err: NSError?

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
    if(err != nil) {

      println(err!.localizedDescription)
      let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Oops! Wrong Details, Try Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

      }
    }else {

      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
      // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
      // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
      var newWeather = WeatherSummary(id:"")

      if let parseJSON = json {

        for weather in parseJSON {

          if let id = weather["employeeName"] as? String{
            println(" LOOK HERE \(id)")
            newWeather.id = id
          }
        }

        weatherArray.append(newWeather)
       self.bioArray = parseJSON
      } else {
        // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

      }
    }
  })

    task.resume()
  }

  func testTwo(){
    println("THIS IS TEST 2")
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.bioArray.count ?? 0
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let weatherSummary: AnyObject = bioArray[indexPath.row]
    if let id = weatherSummary["employeeName"] as? String //Dont know the exact syntax.
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = id
    }

    if let job = weatherSummary["jobTitle"] as? String {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = job
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

**My Issue:**

My Issue is that when I println the returned data it is being printed and I can see it. But my 2nd table view is empty. It does not display the data. I am not sure why the data is not being displayed on the 2nd table view. I can see the data by using println which proves that the API is actually returning real data.

Any suggestions?

Apologies for any mistakes. Please let me know if I have made a mistake and I will fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, submit indnted code, and try to simplify your problem by removing everything which is not related to it....

Comment: @tomsoft thank you for the reply. All the code added is needed to be able to answer the question. The reason I added all the code was because I have no idea where exactly is the problem. So I wanted to give who ever looks at the question as much information as I can to help them answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the issue. Thought I would answer my own question.

Basically I had to reload my table view to display the data.
So I did the following:

```
   didSet{      
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
   }
```

By doing the above my issue was solved. Once I tapped the cell, it took a few seconds but it reloaded my table view once the data was returned from the API and displayed it.

Comment: So didSet method of bioArray didn't work, there was a reloadData method over there? (see my answer?)

Comment: @tafh I have edited my answer. I actually added the tableview.reload within my didSet method. So the didSet method of BioArray did work.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this without seeing the data or the Storyboard. But a few things you should check set a breakpoint and make sure it is calling:

- didSet method of bioArray
- is numberOfRowsInSection hit and returning something?
- is the delegate and datasource set properly?
- is cellForRowAtIndexPath hit and do you have keys named: employeeName and jobTitle

Please check these things first.